# Assign Uinque IDs to elements and target with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of elements that are styled by CSS classes. I need to target these elements individually with JQuery.

For example I have a class `.pass-fail-icon` that uses JQuery `.hasClass()` as such:

```
// Method simply swaps out image based on .hasClass() result
function checkPassed() {
  if ($(".pass-fail-icon").hasClass("passed")) {
    var failSrc = 'img/Fail.svg';
    var passSrc = 'img/Pass.svg';
    $('img[src="' + failSrc + '"]').attr('src', passSrc);

  } else {
    var failSrc = 'img/Fail.svg';
    var passSrc = 'img/Pass.svg';
    $('img[src="' + passSrc + '"]').attr('src', failSrc);

  }
}
```

however I need to target `.pass-fail-icon` individually as I cannot determine yet how long a list will be generated.

How do I give `.pass-fail-icon` a unique ID, and how then do I target it in the above method?

Comment: Why not got through each one, using `$(".pass-fail-icon").each(function () { if ($(this).hasClass("passed")) { ...`?

Comment: Why don't you just select by class: `$(".pass-fail-icon.passed")` will match the icons that have the class, and $(".pass-fail-icon:not(.passed)")` matches the ones that don't.

Comment: It's almost never really necesary to assign IDs to dynamically-generated elements.

Comment: Could you show your HTML, and explain more clearly what's supposed to happen when `checkPassed()` is called?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need Ids for what you are trying to do.

```
var failSrc = 'img/Fail.svg';
var passSrc = 'img/Pass.svg';

//get all pass-fail-icons which don't have a class .passed
$(".pass-fail-icon:not(.passed)").attr('src', failSrc);

//get all pass-fail-icons with a class .passed
$(".pass-fail-icon.passed").attr('src', passSrc);
```

Or the following should work as well

```
$(".pass-fail-icon").attr('src', failSrc);
$(".pass-fail-icon.passed").attr('src', passSrc);
```

*Assign all icons the failSrc and override all that have passed with the passSrc*

Comment: It's not clear that the `.pass-fail-icon` elements are the same as the images.

Comment: I think you missed the `$('img[src="' + failSrc + '"]').attr('src', passSrc);` part

Comment: @Barmar: I made a few assumptions (e.g. .pass-fail-icon is the image)

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel: I don't think that part is actually needed. Whatever the best solution for the problem may be, I am sure this part will not be in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` to iterate through the elements. And you shouldn't create the two variables each time.

```js
function checkPassed() {

  var failSrc = 'img/Fail.svg';
  var passSrc = 'img/Pass.svg';

  $(".pass-fail-icon").each(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("passed")) {
      $('img[src="' + failSrc + '"]').attr('src', passSrc);
    } else {
      $('img[src="' + passSrc + '"]').attr('src', failSrc);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This loop seems unnecessary. The final result is just based on the class of the last icon, because you're overwriting the `src` every time through the loop.

Comment: But there is `$('img[src="' + passSrc + '"]').attr('src', failSrc);` as well

Comment: So the first iteration will toggle all the `failSrc` to `passSrc` or vice versa, then a later itation will toggle them back, and so on.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that is the problemwhich he wants to be solved

Comment: I suspect what he actually wants to do is toggle just one image related to the icon, not all the images.

Comment: Yes I would think that too